# Erro Undefined variable: aloggedin in e Undefined index: submit in

Tags: php

Consegui resolver o outros erros mas quando vou me cadastrar ele da esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: refid in
>   /home/b52uyisu/public_html/register.php on line 70

```
$addaccount = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members VALUES('','$username','$password','$email','$ppemail','$ppemail','$refid','0','0.00','0.00','0.00','$name','$address','$city','$zipcode','$telephone','$country','$date','$uip','$uip','0','0.00','no','./avatar.png','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')");
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: refid in
>   /home/b52uyisu/public_html/register.php on line 76

```
if($refid != '') {

  $qqq = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET totalrefs=totalrefs + '1' WHERE username='$refid'");

}
```

Comment: Com uma linha fica difícil adivinhar seu problema né. Podem ter mudado a config de erros do seu server.

Comment: `$loggedin` e `$aloggedin` são nomes diferentes.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o seu problema. Faça um `var_dump($refid)` antes do erros a ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Não foi definido um valor para a variável.

Ao invés de verificar o valor, você pode ver se ela foi setada usando:

```
if(isset($refid)){
  $qqq = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET totalrefs=totalrefs + '1' WHERE username='$refid'");
}
```

Ou ainda apenas suprimir a mensagem de erro usando um "@" antes da variável:

```
if(@$refid != ""){
      $qqq = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET totalrefs=totalrefs + '1' WHERE username='$refid'");
    }
```